# Remove / Replace class with another class without having an ID - Javascript only

Tags: javascript

Basicly i have two buttons one who will create divs with the class "TargetDummy" and another who should be able to remove the created "TargetDummy". 
The problem is i cant seem to edit the "TargetDummy"divs since they don't have an ID and i can't give them one since there are several of them.

I am looking for a solution in javascript only. My code for creating the "TargetDummy"divs is below

```
 var Div = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(Div).className = "TargetDummy";
```

I thought something like

```
var Dummies = document.getElementsByClassName("TargetDummy");
    Dummies.className = "something";
```

or

```
   Dummies.remove();
```

would do it, but unfortunately not. I am still learning Javascript so go easy on me :)

Comment: Typically you will want to keep some reference to the nodes. jQuery's method of (ab)using the CSS selector has it's limitations. Keep track of all the `TargetDummy` nodes, store them in an `Array`.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a list, so you have to loop over the items in that list and set their class one by one. Are you trying to target just the *last* (most recently created) one, or all of them, or...?

Comment: I am trying to target all of them, so i don't think i would be needing an `Array`. I just can't figure out how to change or remove the class form the element..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply hide the Divs, you could loop through them and give them a new class via the `className` property.

Example JS:

```
var Dummies = document.getElementsByClassName("red");
function addNewClass() {
    for(var i = 0; i < Dummies.length; i++) {
        Dummies[i].className = "newClass";
        Dummies[i--].className = "newClass"
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPZNJN

Comment: That is pretty neat i will check if that solves it right away :)

Comment: Please explain why you are setting the class for `Dummies[i]` _and_ `Dummies[i--]` inside the loop – I doubt that this is obvious to a JS beginner.

Comment: @CBroe To be honest, I don't know. I though just `Dummies[i]` would have done it.  I just experimented.

Comment: Well, `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, and those are by definition “live”, meaning whenever you access it, it always reflects the _current_ state of the DOM. So after you remove (or overwrite) the `red` class for the first node, that node “falls out” of that list, all following nodes move up by one index, and the length of the list is one less than it was before. I assumed you were aware of that, and accounted for that fact by using the `i`/`i--` “magic” …

Comment: A more common way of dealing with this is to loop through the list “backwards”, from last to first – that way, the fact that the length changes while elements inside the list are manipulated doesn’t matter, and the index of nodes still in the list doesn’t change either (since only the last node is manipulated in each iteration).